# Is this light-switch wiring safe and up to code? Kasa wifi switch next to 3-way rocker switch

Tags: electrical, switch, multiway-switch, smart-switch, smart-home

My house was built in 1979.

Today I replaced these 2 lights switches.

The left switch was a simple switch. The right one was a 3-way switch (i.e. there is another switch that also controls the same ceiling light).

## Original wiring

[image: original wiring]

## My diagram of the original wiring

It shows:

- 3 bundles of wires coming from the top of the wall box and 1 from the bottom-left.
- The circles are screw nut caps
- Blue lines represent white wires (I assume "neutral")
- 2 loose red wires (which were connected to the right switch)
- 2 loose black wires (which were connected to the left switch)
- 2 loose green (copper) wires (each switch was connected to 1)
- 1 loose white wire (which was connected to the right switch)

[image: diagram]

## Is what I did here safe and up to code?

2 mins: https://photos.app.goo.gl/BZxXbzoxf8EXxTsi6

### Secondary questions out of curiosity

- Why are ground wires from all 4 bundles clumped together (shown at 0:32)? Is it ok that they don't have a screw nut?
- I'm a complete newbie. I would have assumed that the left and right switches would have *nothing* to do with each other. Yet there is mixing of wires from the 4 bundles (instead of there being 2 totally separate pairs of bundles). What am I misunderstanding?

## Here is the final result, which works:

[image: after]

Comment: If they are on the same breaker, it is okay to connect the neutrals together.  The white wire on the switch should be marked as not a neutral

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for your response!